# XML Parsing child element parsing in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am trying following task but I dont know how to parse data between paragraph tag i.e "My Name is ABC".Getting problem. Please help me.I am using NSXML class
Thanks in advance.

```
<myData>&#60;p>&#60;a href="http:www.abc.com">&#60;img src="http://def.jpg?x=130&amp;y=85&amp;q=85&amp;sig=M.3HKJz72rTrMLB5sXIN4Q--" align="left" height="85" width="130" alt="Network is not present" border="0" />&#60;/a>***My name is ABC*** &#60;/p>&#60;br clear="all"/></myData>
```

Also How to get link for src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

To get attribute:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser*) parser didStartElement:(NSString*) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*) namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString*) qName attributes:(NSDictionary*) attributeDict
```

attributeDict - this dictionary contains all the attributes for the current tag.

You can obtain the string between the tags using the method

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

where the string would be 'My name is ABC' in your case.

So the algorithm is:
1. Get the current tag and save the appropriate state (using parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:)
2. Append the string from the ( parser:foundCharacters:)
3. When the tag ends add that string to container or do whatever you want (parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:)

This is very simplified version. You can learn the basics of NSXMLParser from this tutorial: [link](http://markstruzinski.com/?p=47)